# Cannot resolve symbol "R" in Android Studio but no problem to compile

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I find this very useful code from github:

https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothLeTerminal

I wanted to use the app and make my own edits.
So I clone the app and I use android studio. I manage to build the project with gradle, to upload the app on my phone and use the app without any problems.

However when I started to edit the code I noticed a message from my IDE:

`Cannot resolve symbol "R"`

I look for anwser as usual by googeling it. I tried lots of things from the topics online:

- Restart android studio
- Rebuild the project
- Clean the project (gradle)
- See if there is any errors in the xml (no errors)

I used exatly the same code from the repository.

Environment:

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.0.2-arch1-1-ARCH
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.0.2-arch1-1-ARCH

Comment: try invalidate cache + restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr: upgrade your Android Studio to 3.3 or newer**

The issue here is that the project is using the Android Gradle Plugin version 3.3.0 and you are using an older (than that) Android Studio version 3.2.1.

In AGP 3.3 the support for "light R classes" was added - it means that in libraries the R.java sources are not generated anymore and instead the R.jar (compiled) bytecode is generated directly. That means the IDE cannot rely on the R sources anymore and uses R.txt (from AARs) and its own resource parsers to load the R class information into memory. Because of this, the older Android Studio doesn't know how to do this, and therefore is saying the R classes are missing.

To fix it please upgrade your Android Studio to 3.3.0 or newer.

Comment: I can't update my android studio there is a problem: https://i.imgur.com/2lwnNj7.png

Comment: Uninstall the current one and download the new one from https://developer.android.com/studio/

Comment: Ok, so I finnaly manage to update to the latest version of android studio on archlinux and there is no this "cannot resolve symbol R" error anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it builds when setting `chmod +x ./gradlew`:

```
git clone https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothLeTerminal
cd SimpleBluetoothLeTerminal
chmod +x ./gradlew
./gradlew assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 31s
26 actionable tasks: 26 executed
```

and there's `R`:

```
intermediates/javac/debug/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/classes/de/kai_morich/simple_bluetooth_le_terminal/R.class
```